# fullCalendar (year view) each month in line

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make such a calendar using the fullCalendar library. I have a 3*4 calendar grid and I need to change it so that the month is displayed on one line and the months are one under one.

Like this:
[image]

I tried to do this with CSS, but the event is not displayed correctly. For example, I click on the cell 03/20/2023 and 03/29/2023 is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing (we are on version 6), fullCalendar does not support anything like this unfortunately.

All the available views and the options to configure them are described [in the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc). I cannot think of anything from there which would even get close to what you've put in your picture.

I think your options are:

1. Put in a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) and wait
2. Put in a feature request, get it accepted and [contribute the necessary code yourself](https://fullcalendar.io/contributing)
3. Attempt to make your own [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js)
4. Search for a different product which might meet your needs.